# How can I use getElementsByClassName with jQuery selector :not() selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to select and click on elements with the class ".foo" that do not contain the class ".bar".

I'd like to use code like this but it isn't working:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('foo:not(bar)'); 
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { 
    inputs[i].click(); 
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` is not a jQuery function ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.foo:not(.bar)');
```

Or as you have `jquery` in your tags:

```
$('.foo:not(.bar)').each( function() {
    $( this ).click();
});
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this, the `querySelectorAll()` method, isn't backwards compatible with Internet Explorer (as so very many things are not...) less than 9 (I *think*, but I'm not entirely sure, it *could* be 10).

Comment: @DavidThomas anyway I've provided jQuery version too. And jquery is in question tags. If OP didn't use jQuery he need to ask for another solutions.

Comment: Works perfectly, will select as best answer but you were just so fast it won't let me yet!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.filter()` function to first select all `foo`s without `bar`s:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEYWr/2/)

**CSS**

```
.foo, .bar{
    padding:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
// get all foos and begine filtering
$('.foo').filter(function(){

    // show what class each div has
    $(this).text($(this).attr('class'));

    // translates into: IF bar not exist then return this element
    return !$(this).hasClass('bar');

// color the divs yellow
}).css('background-color','yellow');
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='foo'></div>
<div class='foo bar'></div>
<div class='foo bar'></div>
<div class='foo'></div>
<div class='foo'></div>
<div class='foo bar'></div>
<div class='foo'></div>
<div class='foo bar'></div>
```